# How can I compare and change cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. In both sheets I have a column (B) where each row is a different name:

[image: Example]

Sheet 'A' has names in the column, these names are 'leading'. 
Sheet 'B' also has names in this column, these names CAN BE outdated.

What I want: A macro which can check the names.

- delete the names in Sheet B which are not (anymore) in Sheet A (delete entire affecting row)
- Add the names from sheet A which are not (yet) in sheet B in new rows

What I have so far:

```
Sub DeleteRowsThatDoNotMatch()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim thisRow As Long
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim dic2 As Variant
Dim OutArr As Variant

xTitleId = "Test"
Set Rng1 = Application.Selection
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Welke data moet gewijzigd worden? :", xTitleId, Rng1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Rng2 = Application.InputBox("Selecteer de nieuwe waardes:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set Rng1 = Rng1.Columns(1)
Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr2 = Rng2.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr2, 1)
    xKey = arr2(i, 1)
    dic2(xKey) = ""
Next
thisRow = Rng1.Rows.Count
Do While thisRow > 0
    If Not dic2.Exists(Rng1.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value) Then
        Rng1.Cells(thisRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    thisRow = thisRow - 1

Loop

End Sub
```

This works as expected; the problem is adding the names which ARE in Sheet A but not (yet) in Sheet B.

Comment: The code cannot work as expected if it has a problem adding the names in sheet A which are not in sheet B. Please create a [mcve] and explain what about adding the names to sheet B from Sheet A that is causing you trouble. I know you probably didn't do this intentionally, but in effect, you are asking us to write your code for you, as you have not shown the attempt to do what needs done.